# How can show variable in UI in django from view function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want to show value of pro in UI but not getting , here is my test view function code .value of pro is getting from previous function using django session variable.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def test(request):
    pro = request.session.get('j')
    print("Request ID from Index View : ", pro)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is Valid")
            selected = form.cleaned_data.get('myfield')
            print(selected)

        else:
            # rq = request_id["request_id"]
            s = sql()
            query = f"""update request_form_db.request_form_mymodel
                                                   set is_approved=1
                                                   where request_id = '{pro}' """
            print(query)
            s.update_query(query)
            print("Updated Successfully")

            form = TestForm()
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'pro': pro}
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

Here is my html code test.html

```
<form action ="{% url 'test' %}" method="POST">
    <div class="form_data">

        {% csrf_token %}
         <br><br>

        {{form.myfield}}
         <label><b>Git Id</b></label> <br><br>

<br><br>
        {{form.pro}}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

form.myfield returns what i want but value of pro variable not getting.please help

Answer (score 0):

Just pass same key as you created in context. you dont have to use `{{ form.pro }}`

```
context = {'form': form, 'pro': pro}
```

In html you can render with:

```
{{ pro }}
```